# Rule of thumb for automatically determining if a signal has seasonality and its periodicity from ACF?

Tags: python, autocorrelation, seasonality

I have around 1000 different time series, where I want to detect if each time series has seasonality in it, so that I can perform seasonal decomposition.

I want to try and automatically determine if seasonality is present based on the ACF of the signal. I only want to say that it is seasonality if there is a clear and distinct peak in the ACF, so that it is robust against noise and trend.

I am then using the function [find_peaks](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html) from `scipy.signal` which is meant to be able to automatically find the peaks of a signal, problem is that there are many parameters you can fine tune. I was hoping that there exists some rule of thumb for how to set these parameters in  order to pick up seasonality even if there are some small level shifts or noisy data.

**So basically what I am wondering, those anyone have any experience or ideas on how to correctly set these parameters, and which would be the most important for the task at hand?**

The parameters I am able to tune are

- **height**. Required height of peaks. Either a number, None, an array matching x or a 2-element sequence of the former. The first element is always interpreted as the minimal and the second, if supplied, as the maximal required height.
- **threshold**
  Required threshold of peaks, the vertical distance to its neighboring samples. Either a number, None, an array matching x or a 2-element sequence of the former. The first element is always interpreted as the minimal and the second, if supplied, as the maximal required threshold.
- **distance**
  Required minimal horizontal distance (>= 1) in samples between neighbouring peaks. Smaller peaks are removed first until the condition is fulfilled for all remaining peaks.
- **prominence**
  Required prominence of peaks. Either a number, None, an array matching x or a 2-element sequence of the former. The first element is always interpreted as the minimal and the second, if supplied, as the maximal required prominence.
- **width**
  Required width of peaks in samples. Either a number, None, an array matching x or a 2-element sequence of the former. The first element is always interpreted as the minimal and the second, if supplied, as the maximal required width.
- **wlen**
  Used for calculation of the peaks prominences, thus it is only used if one of the arguments prominence or width is given. See argument wlen in peak_prominences for a full description of its effects.
- **rel_height**
  Used for calculation of the peaks width, thus it is only used if width is given. See argument rel_height in peak_widths for a full description of its effects.
- **plateau_size**
  Required size of the flat top of peaks in samples. Either a number, None, an array matching x or a 2-element sequence of the former. The first element is always interpreted as the minimal and the second, if supplied as the maximal required plateau size.

Example of ACF where I want to pick up seasonality

[image: ![enter image description here]

Example of ACF where I **don't** want to pick up seasonality

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't use ACF. your signals are long enough to run FFT based analysis. you could also get the periodogram. these are better at extracting periods.

Answer (score 0):

I'd more be more likely to use ARIMA (Autoregressive Integrated Moving Average) or SARIMA (Seasonally ARIMA) models in Python using
from statsmodels.tsa.arima.model import ARIMA or statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose. The ARIMA model uses the p,d, q functionality for looking at the autoregressive,  d the number of differences required to make the time series stationery (essential for ARIMA/SARIMA analysis) and q is the moving average factor. If performing SARIMA then P,D,Q are also used and x is the frequency of the pattern. In python you can use auto_arima from the pmd package

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/312682)